# How to evenly space Navbar elements in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Building a bootstrap naviation for website.

I'm having some trouble working out how best to space out the nav link elements on my navbar (and continue to look good for mobile).

My navbar code is:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul id="menu-main-nav" class="navbar-nav">
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-42"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-963" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-963"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-40" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-40" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I currently have four nav elements. I first thought about adding width=25% to the nav-link class. But think that will then creat a problem for the mobile view.

Also what if I end up having a fifth item in my nav bar (added from WordPress Appearnce > Menus) how could I make my code adapt to that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the `.nav-fill` to equally space the items, and `w-100` (width:100%) class to make it full width...

https://www.codeply.com/go/djlHAC3uux

```
<ul id="menu-main-nav" class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
     <li id="menu-item-42" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-42"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">HOME</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-963" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-963"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">SERVICES</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-40" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">ABOUT US</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-40" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="XXX" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: Cool, what does w-100 do?

Comment: Having issue adding those two classes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208421/add-classes-to-wordpress-menu-ul-element

Comment: Thx. What does menu-item-963, menu-item-42 do? Are they random?

Comment: So helpful! In my case it wasn't working *at first*. I have a custom two-row nav menu, and I needed to use these on both the **div** with `navbar-collapse` and the **ul** with `navbar-nav`. Still works in Bootstrap 5 btw, in case anyone is wondering.