# Filling up the entire width of bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so I'll get straight to it, I'm using Bootstrap 4 trying to fill the entire with of my navbar (minus the margin). I understand this question has been asked before, I first viewed a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094948/how-to-evenly-space-navbar-elements-in-bootstrap-4) and tried using the `.nav-fill` class to accomplish this, but that was unsuccessful.

I want to have my navbar centred and fill the entire content with a margin on either side. Here is the code I currently have, I can't seem to figure it out.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: #393939
}



/*

-=-=- NAVIGATION BAR -=-=-

*/
#header-nav {
 background-color: #262626;
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
#header-nav .container {
 max-width: max-content;
}
*/

.navlink {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #C9C9C9;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background:
  linear-gradient(white, white)
  bottom
  /100% 0px
  no-repeat;
 transition: 0.2s all;
}

.navlink:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-size: 100% 4px;
}

.active {
 color: #FFF;
}



/*

-=-=- SOCIAL MEDIA -=-=-

*/

.social-icon {
 float: right;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">
  
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
 

 </head>



 <body>

  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
     <a class="active navlink" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
<!--     <a class="social-icon navbar-text" href="#discord"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a>-->
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't picture the image you were trying to create. Can you show me with an example ?

Comment: Sure thing @CanUver I couldn't exactly find an example but here is a very rough drawing colour coded, this is the extent of my artistic abilities [imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/RHO2rdm). If you run the code snippet and hover over any one of the links you'll see a white bar come up, that is the space of each link, and I want that it to stretch across the entire thing, which they don't right now. Not the entire screen, just where the links go, on the sides there is a margin.

Comment: what about using css grid-container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid-container:

```
<div class="container grid-container">
      <a class="active navlink" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
      <a class="navlink" href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
      <a class="navlink" href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
      <a class="navlink" href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
</div>

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container > a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[mdboootstrap example](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/milkytech/2183729)